# jquery ul li first-child change color

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I am working for a simple menu, click each top menu, open sub menu, and set the first-child different background-color.

Code in here: http://jsfiddle.net/X3Dey/

Thanks.

​

Comment: so what is your question exactly ?

Comment: @MMC, pls see the `jsfiddle`, I want click the top menu, show the sub menu, then the first-child menu change bg color to '#e9aa9e'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).children('.sub-menu-wrap').children().first().css('background','#e9aa9e');
```

there you go http://jsfiddle.net/X3Dey/6/

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to select the parent element of the element you actually want to select (I believe):

```
$(this).children('.sub-menu-wrap').css('display','block');
$(this).children('.sub-menu-wrap:first-child').css('background','#e9aa9e');
```

Should change to (notice I am chaining the function calls instead of creating a whole new selection):

```
$(this).children('.sub-menu-wrap').css('display','block').children().first().css('background','#e9aa9e');
```

The `:first-child` pseudo-selector filters the elements it's applied to, not their children, you have to explicitly select the child elements and then limit to the first one.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/X3Dey/4/

You can optimize your code by using less selectors, chaining where possible, and using DOM traversal functions rather than string pseudo-selectors:

```
$('.menu').click(function(){

    //reset all menu items
    $('.sub-menu-wrap').css('display','none').children().css('background','d2ff2d');

    //now run the code on the selected menu items
    $(this).children('.sub-menu-wrap').css('display','block').children().first().css('background','#e9aa9e');
});
```

Here is a demo of this code: http://jsfiddle.net/X3Dey/5/